# Llenar select2 múltiple desde array

Tags: php, jquery, select2

Quiero llenar un select2 múltiple dependiendo del cliente seleccionado (Livewire).

Mi blade al cambiar select cliente:

```
$('#client').on('change', function (e) {                                
     Livewire.emit('changeClient',parseInt( e.target.value))
});
```

Mi componente al escuchar:

```
protected $listeners = ['changeClient' => 'changeClient'];

public  function changeClient($id)
{      
  // $this->sales=Sale::find($id);  
  // $this->emit('clientChange',$this->contratos->id); 
  $this->sales=Sale::where(['client_id'=>$id])->select(['id','afip_cbte_id','pto_venta','numero','fecha','total'])->orderby('id', 'asc')->get();
   $data=[];
  foreach($this->sales as $sales){
 
    array_push($data,[
        'Id' =>$sales->id,
        'nro'=> str_pad($sales->pto_venta, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) .'-'.str_pad($sales->numero, 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
       ]);
  }
 
 $this->cobranza->client_id=$id;
 $this->emit('clientChange',$data); 
  
}
```

Mi blade al escuchar componente:

```
window.onload=function(){
   
    Livewire.on('clientChange',(data)=>{ 
        console.log(data);
        for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++) {
           var o = new Option(data[i], data[i]);
            console.log(data[i]['Id']);
            $(o).html(data[i]['nro']);
            $("#factura").append(o);
            $("#factura").val(data[i]['Id']); 
        //   $("#factura").select2('data', {id: data[i]['Id'], text: data[i]['nro']});     
        }
       //  $("#factura").select2({tags:[data]});
        
    })           
}
```

Esto me funciona hasta cierto punto, pues solo me llena el texto del select, no el id. He probado diferentes formas, pero nunca logro que me llene el value del select2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era mucho más fácil de lo que me complicaba, lo logré así

```
 window.onload=function(){
       
        Livewire.on('clientChange',(data)=>{ 
            console.log(data);               
            $("#factura").select2({
             data: data
            })
            
        }) 
       
    }
```

Comment: No olvides explicar tu código, y [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.